# Access to full featured IA_NetworkView

Tags: graphileon

I have a Neo4j query producing a graph, and I want to show the result in a `IA_NetworkView` (or better `IA_YFilesView`, to have hierarchical view of the graph).
So I add the `IA_NetworkView` (or `IA_YFilesView`) label to the node connected with the query node, and Graphileon produces a nice view representing the result graph:
[image]
This node is then connected to the Graphileon "Properties panel" node, in order to let the user click on a node or relationship and edit the attributes.
The problem is, the user should also be able to add/remove nodes and relationships, to select a hierarchical view (if using IA_YFilesView), and perform other actions that are possible in the embedded IA_NetworkView/IA_YFilesView in Graphileon, shown when executing a query, or when viewing the logic of an application:
[image]
Is there a way to connect my app graph to the embedded network view? I guess I should connect to some node, as I already did with the Properties panel, but I couldn't find anything

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want the NV/YFV in which you display your Supplier nodes to have the same functionality (add/remove/link nodes and rels) as the default NV/YFV ?

Comment: Exactly, to give the user the freedom to modify graphs on db (no security issues, just an internal prototype for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default NV/YFV has a number of context options that activate functions to add / edit and connect nodes. You can add those (or just the ones you need) to the YFV/NV in which you display the suppliers. On Slack (https://join.slack.com/t/graphileon-users/shared_invite/zt-fjrtq8wi-fdFNJWTBz1l5Xd7BseBclw) we may be able to help you further too (maybe even shed some radio-active light on this)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to add these connections and see what happens